# Winform webbrowser control not rendering in IE8 mode in a machine having IE9

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, internet-explorer-9, webbrowser-control

I have IE9 installed in my machine(Windows 7), when i run winform webbrowser control with registry key 8000 (SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION) for current user on a 32 bit machine. i can still see winform webbrowser control rendering in IE9 mode, I am expecting it to render with IE8 compatibility mode.

With IE10 in  my machine and with same registry settings, i can see , the page is rendered in IE8 compatibility mode. But we have to support IE8, IE9 and IE10. Most of the users are on IE9 .

So how to make winform webbrowser control in a machine having IE9 to render in IE8 compatibility mode. Please help

Comment: It's not an duplicate. Pls recheck.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/926395/winform-webbrowser-control-not-rendering-in-ie8-mode-in-a-machine-having-ie9

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions for this. Please check this [link](https://sampathdr.wordpress.com/2014/04/24/html-5-content-in-wpf-browser-control/) to more details.

1)  Change Registry to use IE 9 or your latest IE version in WPF Browser control.
2)  Add Meta tag to web page which IE version should used to render.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content=" IE=edge " >
or
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" >
```

Comment: Pls read my question again. i want my webbrowser control to render in IE8 mode with IE9 installed in my machine. I had applied registry settings, Still not working.

Comment: Did you try with registry value 8888?

Comment: Yes. still not rendering in IE8 mode.